# How do I connect MassTransit to Postgres via Dapper to store Sagas?

Tags: c#, postgresql, dapper, masstransit

I can't find a working example anywhere, but in the docks to MassTransit there is an example for MSSQL (it has SqlClient dependencies and does not read the connection string for Postgre). Or is it possible only through EFCore + Npgsql?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MassTransit has support for PostgreSQL using either Entity Framework Core or Dapper.

Nothing special to configure MassTransit, just follow the examples.

For instance, the outbox sample [configured PostgreSQL](https://github.com/MassTransit/Sample-Outbox/blob/master/src/Sample.Worker/Program.cs#L78) using EF Core. I'd suggest this route, honestly. Dapper is a little too "raw" for most.

It looks like Dapper is [hard-coded to SQL Server syntax](https://github.com/MassTransit/MassTransit/blob/2aea05c1e8d3c0c33e4f9ea65f24c437a37241e9/src/Persistence/MassTransit.DapperIntegration/DapperIntegration/Saga/DapperDatabaseContext.cs#L81). So it would not work with PostgreSQL.